# Is necessary to use a RMI Server in Esper 8 in order to Runtime deploy Esper Workflows

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I'm trying to make an Esper application thats permits me to Runtime deploy dataflow based patterns. In order to implement this, I used a RMI based server for sending patterns, but thinking on that, it may be not necessary. There is a way embedded in the engine to implement my approach?

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Esper compiler and runtime any way you want. There are no requirements by Esper on anything. Therefore whether you use RMI or something else is all up to you.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I think that I have asked my question in a wrong way. My doubt is if Esper contains a way to do that I want to do without using a RMI server o anything else. I want to run my engine and, without stop it, add new dataflows in Runtime.

Comment: Yes the API allows to add/remove anything at runtime.